# How to send Datetime of a group of GATT characteristics?

Tags: datetime, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am implementing an IoT device that can communicate with a smartphone via BLE protocol. The IoT device sends periodically some environnemental parameters **(ex: Temperature, Humidity, Pressure ...)**.

In the IoT device software, I created one GATT Service that contains many characteristics **(each characteristic ==> each environnemental parameters)**. ***Now I need to send datetime of characteristics when I send new data (new measurements of environnemental parameters), but I don't know which method of the following to choose :***

***1.*** Create another characteristic (**Datetime**), and in the software update datetime and the other characteristics at the same time.
***2.*** Add datetime to each characteristic : **Attribute = Environnemental parameter + datetime**.

***What is the 'correct' way to send datetime in my use case ?***

Comment: The officially adopted GATT profiles and services are documented at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/ . I would have thought they might be useful to see what is done in those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring documentation of some official standard characteristics and services, I found that the correct way to add time is to add a timestamp to each characteristic. The timestamp has the same description as the Date Time characteristic (Standard characteristic).

To sum up, the correct way to add time is the answer 2 (of my question).